# How to reset a postponed / declined message in TPL Dataflow

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, pipeline, tpl-dataflow

I am using TDF for my application which works great so far, unfortunately i stumbled upon a specific problem where it seems it can not be handled directly with existing Dataflow mechanisms:

I have N producers (in this case BufferBlocks) which are all linked to only 1 (all to the same) ActionBlock. This block always processes 1 item at a time, and also only has capacity for 1 item.

To the link from the producers to the ActionBlock I also want to add a filter, but the special case here is that the filter condition can change independently of the processed item, and the item must not be discarded!
So basically i want to process all items, but the order / time can change when an item will be processed.

Unfortunately I learned, that if an item is "declined" once -> the filter condition evaluates false, and if this item is not passed to another block (e.g. NullTarget), the target block does not retry the same item (and does not re-evaluate the filter).

```
public class ConsumeTest
  {
    private readonly BufferBlock<int> m_bufferBlock1;
    private readonly BufferBlock<int> m_bufferBlock2;
    private readonly ActionBlock<int> m_actionBlock;

    public ConsumeTest()
    {
      m_bufferBlock1 = new BufferBlock<int>();
      m_bufferBlock2 = new BufferBlock<int>();

      var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() { BoundedCapacity = 1, MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 };
      m_actionBlock = new ActionBlock<int>((item) => BlockAction(item), options);

      var start = DateTime.Now;
      var elapsed = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);

      m_bufferBlock1.LinkTo(m_actionBlock, x => IsTimeElapsed(start, elapsed));
      m_bufferBlock2.LinkTo(m_actionBlock);

      FillBuffers();
    }

    private void BlockAction(int item)
    {
      Console.WriteLine(item);
      Thread.Sleep(2000);
    }

    private void FillBuffers()
    {
      for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
      {
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
          m_bufferBlock1.Post(i);
        }
        else
        {
          m_bufferBlock2.Post(i);
        }
      }
    }

    private bool IsTimeElapsed(DateTime start, TimeSpan elapsed)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("checking time elapsed");
      return DateTime.Now > (start + elapsed);
    }

    public async Task Start()
    {
      await m_actionBlock.Completion;
    }
  }
```

The code sets up a testing pipeline, and fills the two buffers with odd and even numbers. Both BufferBlocks are connected to one single ActionBlock that only prints the "processed" number and waits 2 secs.

The filter condition between m_bufferBlock1 and the m_actionBlock checks (for testing purposes) if 1 minute is elapsed since we started the whole thing.

If we run this, it generates the following output:

```
1
checking time elapsed
3
5
7
9
11
13
15
17
19
```

As we can see, the ActionBlock takes the first element from the BufferBlock without filter, then tries to take an element from the BufferBlock with a filter. The filter evaluates false and it continues to take all elements from the block without the filter.

My expectation was that after an element from the BufferBlock without filter has been processed, it tries to take the element from the other BufferBlock with the filter again, evaluating it again.

This would be my expected (or desired) result:

```
1
checking time elapsed
3
checking time elapsed
5
checking time elapsed
7
checking time elapsed
9
checking time elapsed
11
checking time elapsed
13
checking time elapsed
15
// after timer has elapsed take elements also from other buffer
2
17
4
19
```

My question now is, is there a way to "reset" the already "declined" message so that it is evaluated again, or is there another way by modeling it differently? To outline, it is NOT important that they really are pulled from both Buffers strictly alternating! (because i know that this is scheduling dependent and it is totally fine if from time to time 2 items from the same block are dequeued)
But it is important that the "declined" message must not be discarded or re-queued as the order within one buffer is important.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

One idea is to refresh the link between the two blocks, periodically or on demand. Implementing a periodically refreshable [`LinkTo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblock.linkto) is not very difficult. Here is an implementation:

```
public static IDisposable LinkTo<TOutput>(this ISourceBlock<TOutput> source,
    ITargetBlock<TOutput> target, Predicate<TOutput> predicate,
    TimeSpan refreshInterval, DataflowLinkOptions linkOptions = null)
{
    if (source == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
    if (target == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(target));
    if (predicate == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(predicate));
    if (refreshInterval < TimeSpan.Zero)
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(refreshInterval));
    linkOptions = linkOptions ?? new DataflowLinkOptions();

    var locker = new object();
    var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    var token = cts.Token;
    var currentLink = source.LinkTo(target, linkOptions, predicate);
    var loopTask = Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                await Task.Delay(refreshInterval, token).ConfigureAwait(false);
                currentLink.Dispose();
                currentLink = source.LinkTo(target, linkOptions, predicate);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            lock (locker) { cts.Dispose(); cts = null; }
        }
    }, token);

    _ = Task.Factory.ContinueWhenAny(new[] { source.Completion, target.Completion },
        _ => { lock (locker) cts?.Cancel(); }, token, TaskContinuationOptions.None,
        TaskScheduler.Default);

    return new Unlinker(() =>
    {
        lock (locker) cts?.Cancel();
        // Wait synchronously the task to complete, ignoring cancellation exceptions.
        try { loopTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult(); } catch (OperationCanceledException) { }
        currentLink.Dispose();
    });
}

private struct Unlinker : IDisposable
{
    private readonly Action _action;
    public Unlinker(Action disposeAction) => _action = disposeAction;
    void IDisposable.Dispose() => _action?.Invoke();
}
```

Usage example:

```
m_bufferBlock1.LinkTo(m_actionBlock, x => IsTimeElapsed(start, elapsed),
    refreshInterval: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
```

The link between the `m_bufferBlock1` and the `m_actionBlock` will be refreshed every 10 seconds, until one of the two blocks completes.